# How Do I Make a STL Stack Use a Template Parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, stack

Short and sweet: I'm trying to use C++'s STL stack in a way that accepts generic variables. Based on code I found online, I'm trying this:

```
template <class T>
class ingredient{};
stack <ingredient> Sandwich;
```

Intuitively, this seems like it should work, but I get an "invalid declaration" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have no `ingredient` class; you instead have an `ingredient<T>` class.  You'd need to instantiate the `stack` with `stack<ingredient<T> >` for some type `T`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::stack`, as well as other standard containers, must be instantiated with a concrete type. So assuming that you have

```
class ingredient {};
```

You declare a stack of ingredients:

```
std::stack<ingredient> Sandwich;
```

If `ingredient` itself is a template, you have to specify it's parameter when you instantiate the stack:

```
std::stack<ingredient<int>> Sandwich;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it doesn't actually solve the issue. I've updated the code to include class ingredient{}; and changed the stack parameter as suggested, and it still gives me errors.

Comment: @Mock You need to specify the errors. My guess is you need to `#include <stack>` and prefix your declaration with `std::` like in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ingredient` is not a type. `ingredient<T>` is a type.

You need to use another type, which will be used to define an `ingredient`.

For example:

```
struct Ham {};

stack <ingredient<Ham>> Sandwich;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  `stack` is a `template` that takes a type as its first parameter.  You cannot give it a `template` instead.

You could get something like a `boost::any` or `boost::variant` and store those in a `stack`.  `variant` is a tagged union with helper functions that can store one of a set of types.  `any` is a type-safe value semantics wrapper around the rough equivalent of a `void*`: you can get at the value, but only if you know the exact type.